# Twig double quote variable inside a function call

Tags: php, symfony, escaping, twig

I'm trying to predefine a value in a select.

This works:

```
{{ form_widget(value.children.activity, { value:"1" }) }}
```

This does not work :

```
{{ form_widget(value.children.activity, { value:object.id }) }}
```

Where object id also is 1

So I tried [escaping](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html), putting quotes and echoing the variable and all dirty solutions I could think of, but it seems that I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found out!

It must be a string, so a quick dirty solution is:

```
{% set foo = "" ~ object.id %}
{{ form_widget(value.children.activity, { value:foo }) }}
```

Comment: just a question did your try it with parentheses around `object.id´?

Comment: No, i did not, does it cast an int to a string?

Answer (score 0):

*This should work*

```
{{ form_widget(value.children.activity, { value: object.id|trim }) }}
```